# How to attach a file in share point via Microsoft graph API?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

How can I Attach a photo into my list item in share point via Microsoft graph API?

The `listItem` documentation has a sneaky caveat right at the end which says that files/document libraries are treated as `driveItems`:

For document libraries, the `driveItem` relationship exposes the `listItem` as a `driveItem`

Right, so does that mean that all files are then related to `driveItems`? It seems closer as the `driveItem` docs talk about the following example (indicating site-related content which is SharePoint)

> PUT /sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content

But the above route doesn't specify a `list-id` and neither an `item-id`. So how does that fit in?